# set own video frame in the main screen on facetime

Tags: facetime

is it possible, when using facetime, to increase the size of my own video frame? as in skype where I can set my own video frame in the main screen and my friend video as the little frame in the corner. I couldn't find an option for that, I can only move the little frame across the screen, but can't increase the size.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the size can not be changed. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html